# My simple camera app (android) won't load the camera view after the first attempt

Tags: android, camera, android-camera, runtime-permissions

I'm just trying to make a simple camera app that uses runtime permissions...it seems to load fine the first time the app is launched (asking for the camera permission).  After allowing access, it works...but as soon as I close it and start it up again, it just shows a white image with my icons that won't respond.  I've checked the permissions manually in the app and the camera is still granted access but I think I'm screwing up my permissions code.

Here is the MainActivity code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final int MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CAMERA = 1;
    private Camera mCamera = null;
    private Camera mCameraFront = null;
    private CameraView mCameraView = null;
    public int switchCamera = 1;


//    int permissionCheck = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
//            Manifest.permission.CAMERA);

//    String[] perms = {"android.permission.CAMERA"};


//    int permsRequestCode = 200;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                Manifest.permission.CAMERA)
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

            // Should we show an explanation?
            if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this,
                    Manifest.permission.CAMERA)) {

                // Show an explanation to the user *asynchronously* -- don't block
                // this thread waiting for the user's response! After the user
                // sees the explanation, try again to request the permission.

            } else {

                // No explanation needed, we can request the permission.

                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                        new String[]{Manifest.permission.CAMERA},
                        MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CAMERA);

                try {
                    mCamera = Camera.open(1);//you can use open(int) to use different cameras
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.d("ERROR", "Failed to get camera: " + e.getMessage());
                }
                SwapCamera();

//                if (mCamera != null) {
////                        mCameraView = new CameraView(this, mCamera);//create a SurfaceView to show camera data
////                        FrameLayout camera_view = (FrameLayout)findViewById(R.id.camera_view);
////                        camera_view.addView(mCameraView);//add the SurfaceView to the layout
//                    SwapCamera();
//                }

                //btn to close the application
                ImageButton imgClose = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imgClose);
                imgClose.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        mCamera.setPreviewCallback(null);
                        mCamera.setErrorCallback(null);
                        mCamera.stopPreview();
                        mCamera.release();
                        mCamera = null;
                        System.exit(0);
                    }
                });

//                     btn to switch camera
                ImageButton imgSwitch = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.cameraSwitch);
                imgSwitch.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
//                            switchCamera++;
                    }
                });


            }
        }
    }



    public void SwapCamera() {
        mCameraView = new CameraView(this, mCamera);//create a SurfaceView to show camera data
        FrameLayout camera_view = (FrameLayout)findViewById(R.id.camera_view);
        camera_view.addView(mCameraView);//add the SurfaceView to the layout
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,
                                           String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {

        switch (requestCode) {
            case MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CAMERA: {
                // If request is cancelled, the result arrays are empty.
                if (grantResults.length > 0
                        && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {



                    // permission was granted, yay! Do the
                    // camera-related task you need to do.

                    try{
                        mCamera = Camera.open(1);//you can use open(int) to use different cameras
                    } catch (Exception e){
                        Log.d("ERROR", "Failed to get camera: " + e.getMessage());
                    }

                    if(mCamera != null) {
//                        mCameraView = new CameraView(this, mCamera);//create a SurfaceView to show camera data
//                        FrameLayout camera_view = (FrameLayout)findViewById(R.id.camera_view);
//                        camera_view.addView(mCameraView);//add the SurfaceView to the layout
                        SwapCamera();
                    }

                    //btn to close the application
                    ImageButton imgClose = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.imgClose);
                    imgClose.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View view) {
                            mCamera.setPreviewCallback(null);
                            mCamera.setErrorCallback(null);
                            mCamera.stopPreview();
                            mCamera.release();
                            mCamera = null;
                            System.exit(0);
                        }
                    });

//                     btn to switch camera
                    ImageButton imgSwitch = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.cameraSwitch);
                    imgSwitch.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View view) {
//                            switchCamera++;
                       }
                    });



                } else {

                    // permission denied, boo! Disable the
                    // functionality that depends on this permission.
                }
                return;
            }

            // other 'case' lines to check for other
            // permissions this app might request
        }
    }

    public void onActivityResult() {

    }


}
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are missing "else"

```
if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                Manifest.permission.CAMERA)
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
// your code

} else {
   // stuff with camera
   try{
      mCamera = Camera.open(1);
   } catch (Exception e){
   ...
}
```

Comment: I'm confused where I'm missing the "else"...I have my "try" block with the onRequestPermissionsResult method....should I move it to the onCreate method? (within the "if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                Manifest.permission.CAMERA)
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)" area)

Comment: You should copy it to the onCreate method. @Vlad Matvienko explained.

Answer (score 1):

You only start camera staff in `onActivityResult`, which is called only when you don't have permissions, and request them:

```
if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                Manifest.permission.CAMERA)
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
    ...
}
```

this `if` needs `else` for the case where a permission is already `PERMISSION_GRANTED`. You have to do here the same staff you do in your `onActivityResult`:

```
else {
    try{
                            mCamera = Camera.open(1);//you can use open(int) to use different cameras
                        } catch (Exception e){
                            Log.d("ERROR", "Failed to get camera: " + e.getMessage());
                        }

                        if(mCamera != null) {
    //                        mCameraView = new CameraView(this, mCamera);//create a SurfaceView to show camera data
    //                        FrameLayout camera_view = (FrameLayout)findViewById(R.id.camera_view);
    //                        camera_view.addView(mCameraView);//add the SurfaceView to the layout
                            SwapCamera();
                        }

                        //btn to close the application
                        ImageButton imgClose = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.imgClose);
                        imgClose.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(View view) {
                                mCamera = null;
                                System.exit(0);
                            }
                        });

    //                     btn to switch camera
                        ImageButton imgSwitch = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.cameraSwitch);
                        imgSwitch.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(View view) {
    //                            switchCamera++;
                           }
                        });
}
```

Comment: I've copied the try block to the else statement (just beyond the != to PERMISSION_GRANTED) but I'm still getting the same result...I think I'm misunderstanding your answer

Comment: @fmi, do you get any exception?

Comment: Nope....the first time I load the app, it prompts me with the request....the front facing camera then displays with the 2 icons uptop....after closing the app and reopening, I don't get prompted anymore and I just see a white screen with the 2 icons up top that won't react to touches any more

Comment: can you update a code in your question for me to see maybe I find something.

Comment: I just updated the code but I just noticed that I am getting a warning...my "addView" invocation "may produce a null pointer exception"...it's in my swapCamera() method